# In R, fill first 1000 df rows with value "A", next 1000 df rows with value "B", etc

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
  Keyword                    AdGroup index
  <chr>                      <chr>   <int>
1 memes 2019                 ""          1
2 new movies coming out      ""          2
3 black friday tv deals 2019 ""          3
4 wheel of time tv series    ""          4
5 nitro cold brew            ""          5
6 new tv shows               ""          6
```

I tried the following code:

```
adgroup<- function(){
  browser()
  mytop<-1
  mybot<-1000
  i = 1
  mygroup <- paste0("Adgroup ",i)
  
  while (mytop < 15001153){
    myoutput$AdGroup[myoutput$index >= mytop & myoutput$index <= mybot] <- mygroup
    i<-i+1
    mytop <- mytop + 1000
    mybot <- mybot + 1000
    mygroup <- paste0("Adgroup ",i)
    print(paste0(i," ",mytop))
  }
    
}
```

When I stepped through the code, the first group was filled in with "Adgroup 1".  But, when I looked at the first group after the code completed, it was blank.

Thanks.

Comment: Most likely your issue is that you print the result but don't assign it. However, we don't use `while` loops for such tasks in R. Please show the expected output (not for 1000 repetitions but for 3 repetitions).

Comment: Is `15001153` the number of rows of the df? If yes, why hard code it instead of using `nrow(myoutput)`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like the following?

```
addgroup <- function(x, size = 1000, group = "Adgroup "){
  n <- nrow(x)
  passes <- n %/% size
  remaining <- n %% size
  inx <- seq_len(size) - size
  if(passes){
    for(i in seq_len(passes)){
      inx <- inx + size
      x$AdGroup[inx] <- paste0(group, i)
    }
  }
  if(remaining){
    i <- passes + 1L
    inx <- (inx + size)[seq_len(remaining)]
    x$AdGroup[inx] <- paste0(group, i)
  }
  x
}

addgroup(myoutput, size = 10)
```

---

### Test data creation code

```
set.seed(2021)
n <- 34
myoutput <- data.frame(Keyword = sample(letters, n, TRUE), AdGroup = "")
myoutput$index <- seq_len(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[["group"]] <- (seq_len(nrow(df)) - 1) %/% 1000
```

Comment: Couldn't you explain your answer? Code only answers are many times flagged for revision, like this one was. (Not my flag, BTW).